# Apple push notifications service for server

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I want to use apple push notification service in my server. But someone said you have to use certificate in your server. I researched the internet and I have found tutorials but nobody says the certificate source. I am already using certificate in my app for push service but where can i found the certificates for server ? Can somebody show me a road map ?

Ps: I will use this is my server : https://github.com/argon/node-apn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/

As usual with anything development related to Apple. Create a certificate there and use that.

Remember, for debug applications, you need to use the sandbox push service, while for release applications, you need to use the normal push service. Each require a different certificate.

All this is thoroughly explained in the [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9) and [Provisioning and Development](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1) documents.

Comment: That's for development. You need a distribution one as well for your AppStore version.

Comment: I am developing now I will submit later to app store. But please look at the link in my question I need key.pem file. Where can I find it ?

Comment: That's the private key to your certificate. You can find it in the Mac's KeyChain, and you can export it from there.

Comment: Ok, I created pem file from KeyChain. But it still says you need key.pem and cert.pem. What is the second pem file ?

Comment: The second is the certificate. Export it as PEM.